# MySQL One to Many, Does not have specific Entry

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am sure my title leaves a lot to be desired, but let me try to explain the issue.

I have a table accounts like so:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|    id    |   name    |   email   |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|     1    |   Bob     |bob@bob.com|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have a packages table like so:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
|    id    |package_id | start_date|end_date| acc_id |
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
|     1    |   15      |2014-01-01 |        |  1     |
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

An account can have multiple packages, though they will not have the same package ie two active packages with an package_id of 15.

I need to effectively select all accounts where they do not have an active package with a package_id of 15 or 25. I use the following to determine if the package is active:

```
p.start_date >= NOW() and p.end_date <= NOW() or p.end_date = '0000-00-00' or ISNULL(p.end_date)))
```

I have seen where I can say have a second select in the query, assign the select a name and then use this value to compare. So for example

```
(select * from packages as p where p.start_date >= NOW() and p.end_date <= NOW() or p.end_date = '0000-00-00' or ISNULL(p.end_date))) AND acc_id = accounts.id AND package_id IN(15,25)) AS has_package
```

The i can say do:

```
has_package <= 0
```

So I am looking for something like so, where the account id is the current records id:

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts AS a
WHERE (select * from packages as p where p.start_date >= NOW() and p.end_date <= NOW() or p.end_date = '0000-00-00' or ISNULL(p.end_date))) AND p.acc_id = a.id AND package_id IN(15,25)) <= 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to user group by clause with in sub query like this:

SELECT * 
FROM accounts AS a
WHERE (select * from packages as p where p.start_date >= NOW() and p.end_date <= NOW() or p.end_date = '0000-00-00' or ISNULL(p.end_date))) AND p.acc_id = a.id AND package_id IN(15,25) GROUP BY package_id Having count(package_id) = 1 )